# Prove that if $M=f(M)+\ker(f)$ and $S=\text{End}_R(M)$ is a reduced ring, then $S$ is regular

Tags: ring-theory, modules, injective-module, regular-rings

Consider a right $R$-module  $M$ with a reduced endomorphism ring $S=\text{End}_R(M)$.  If $M=f(M)+\ker(f)$ for every $f\in S$, then prove that $S$ is a regular ring.

**I tried to prove that in the following manner:**

Let $f\in S$.  Then for each $m\in M,m=f(n)+b$ for some $n\in M$ and $b\in \ker(f)$.  Then $f(m)=f^2(n)$.  It follows that $f\in Sf^2$ and $f=gf^2$.  This proves that $S$ is a strongly regular ring.

**More ideas:**  Since for each $m\in M,f(m)=f^2(n)$ for some $n\in M, f(M)=f^2(M)$.  Now we claim that $\ker(f)=\ker(f^2)$ for each $f\in S$.  Suppose not.  Then $\ker(f)\subset\ker(f^2)$ and $$M=\ker(f)+f(M)=\ker(f)+f^2(M)\subset \ker(f^2)+f^2(M)=\ker(f^2)+f(M)\subseteq M=\ker(f)+f(M),$$ which is contradiction.  Thus $\ker(f)=\ker(f^2)$ for each $f\in S$. But again $\ker(f)=\ker(f^2)$ implies $\ker(f)\cap f(M)=0$.   Hence $M=\ker(f)\oplus f(M)$.  This proves that $S$ is regular.

Is this proof okay?  I am requesting for some help.

Comment: Why do you think $f\in Sf^2$ follows from $f(m)=f^2(n)$?  It is not justified, even if it is true.  It would be true if $f(m)=gf^2(m)$ for all $m$, but that is not the case so far.

Comment: I have changed the argument slightly.  Does the newly added content make sense?

Comment: Is that additional argument making sense?

Comment: I don't see why $\ker(f)+f^2(M)\subset \ker(f^2)+f^2(M)$ (strictly) necessarily follows, even when $\ker(f)\subset \ker(f^2)$. That whole line of reasoning can be shortened btw, but since I'm not sure it is going to be useful I'm not writing it out.